# issue when installing php-dev in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, php, php7

I am getting the following error:

```
root@56709:/etc/nginx/conf.d# apt install php7.4-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.4-dev : Depends: libpcre2-dev (>= 10.30) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libssl-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: php7.4-common (= 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.4) but 7.4.11-6+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
              Recommends: pkg-php-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

when running `apt install php7.4-dev` any idea on how to fix it ?

i tried using aptitude instead of apt and here's what i got

```
root@56709:/etc/nginx/conf.d# sudo aptitude install php7.4-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpcre2-16-0{a} libpcre2-32-0{a} libpcre2-dev{ab} libpcre2-posix2{a} libssl-dev{ab} php7.4-dev{b} pkg-php-tools{a} shtool{a}
0 packages upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,295 kB of archives. After unpacking 17.7 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.4-dev : Depends: php7.4-common (= 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.4) but 7.4.11-6+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is installed
 libpcre2-dev : Depends: libpcre2-8-0 (= 10.34-7) but 10.35-5+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is installed
 libssl-dev : Depends: libssl1.1 (= 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2) but 1.1.1g-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is installed
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     libpcre2-dev [Not Installed]
2)     libssl-dev [Not Installed]
3)     php7.4-dev [Not Installed]
```

I am currently on ubuntu 20.0.4 but if i see above i think i am still referring to 16.04 .. need to somehow update the sources ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: no it didn't.. i tried using aptitude and posted the results above

Answer (score 5):

@Henning Kockerbeck's explanation is great.
Here is the 2-line solution presented at [this blog post](https://www.srv24x7.com/php7-4-dev-depends-libssl-dev-but-it-is-not-going-to-be-installed/)

Copy-pasting the code to avoid link-rot in the future:

```
# apt install libssl-dev
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libssl-dev : Depends: libssl1.1 (= 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.9) but 1.1.1d-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This explains the various versions that are in conflict, due to which you might have to "hold" a package to a particular version which appears to `apt` as the not-latest version:

```
# apt-cache policy libssl1.1
libssl1.1:
  Installed: 1.1.1g-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Candidate: 1.1.1g-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
 *** 1.1.1g-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.9 500
        500 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
     1.1.0g-2ubuntu4 500
        500 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

This installs a specific version. Remember that this is a time-bomb and when you want to upgrade later you have remove this version of the package / unhold it.

```
# apt install libssl1.1=1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.9
```

Now the versions are OK and php7.x-dev will install properly

```
# apt-cache policy libssl1.1
libssl1.1:
  Installed: 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.9
  Candidate: 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.9
  Version table:
 *** 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.9 500
        500 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.1.0g-2ubuntu4 500
        500 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

The minor versions above may vary, but the idea is the same - Sury's packages are causing an issue with system's libssl package. There must be  other solutions to keep using Sury's version of libssl, after all he has been maintaining these packages for a decade, which means he must know what he is doing, but I'm not aware of the details of such an alternative approach.

Comment: doing `apt install libssl1.1=1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.14` solved it for me

Comment: The version strings are quite confusing. How can we know which is the correct version or newer version?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have old packages from a PPA installed that throw things into disarray.

You try to install `php7.4-dev`. [That package depends](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/php7.4-dev) on `php7.4-common`. For Ubuntu 20.04, `php7.4-common` actually is `7.4.3-4ubuntu2.4`.

But you already have a `php7.4-common` package installed, namely `7.4.11-6+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1`. This seems to be a package for about eight Ubuntu versions ago, but with a slightly newer PHP version (7.4.11 vs. 7.4.3). So `apt` prefers the supposedly newer package. But `7.4.11-6+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1`from the PPA doesn't work with `php7.4-dev` from Ubuntu 20.04s repositories. So `apt` is throwing up its proverbial hands up and gives up.

If you don't need it anymore, you should remove the PPA and all packages installed from it. Maybe there are additional PPAs or packages throwing things in disarray, but the above seems to be a problem in any case.

Answer (score 0):

`aptitude` output suggests that dependencies can't be met because conflicting packages from a third-party repository are already installed:

> libpcre2-dev : Depends: libpcre2-8-0 (= 10.34-7) but 10.35-5+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is installed

Do you have something about `deb.sury.org` in your package sources (`/etc/apt/sources.list` and subdirectories)?

Have you tried `apt autoremove`? This will remove dependencies of uninstalled package (i.e. automatically installed package that are not required by any installed package).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo apt install libc6=2.31-0ubuntu9.2 libc-bin=2.31-0ubuntu9.2
```

Αfter running this command run:

```
sudo apt install php7.4-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I had received a similar error while installing PHP 8.0, I installed all the dependencies mentioned in `Depends:` and it was solved.